# How to make st the default terminal in linuxmint cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, cinnamon, terminal-emulator, defaults

I have `st` installed in my `$PATH` (in `/usr/local/bin`). But still, I don't see `st` present in `Prefered Applications` list, nor is it present as an option when I run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` in my terminal. How do I set it as default?

Answer (score 3):

If `st` is not listed by `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` you can use

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec <path_to_st>
```

where `<path_to_st>` can be found using `which stterm`<sup>1</sup>. On my system you can find it at `/usr/bin/stterm`. In the following, I am going to assume you have the same location.

#### The Vim issue

After using the above command, the keybinding for the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> by default) will open `st`. But calling Vim from a file manager or anything else using desktop entries will still use the old terminal. For the sake of example, let us consider it is `gnome-terminal` found at `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`.

You can try to solve that by editing Vim's desktop entry:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/vim.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
vim ~/.local/share/applications/vim.desktop
```

```
vim.desktop
-----------
#TryExec=vim
#Exec=vim %F
#Terminal=True
Exec=stterm -e "vim %F"
Terminal=False
```

On my system it works but `st` closes instantly. I tried to replace `stterm` by another terminal emulators and it works so I believe `st` has issues dealing with desktop entries.

#### The brutal solution

Since some programs still use the old `gnome-terminal` the best way to get around the problem is to symlink it to `stterm`:

```
mkdir ~/.local/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/ssterm ~/.local/bin/gnome-terminal
```

This solves all problems but is not an elegant solution. Don't forget to `rm ~/.local/share/applications/vim.desktop` if you try this solution after the previous one.

---

<sup>1</sup>on Debian and Ubuntu based systems, `st` is packaged as `stterm`.

Comment: Although `Ctrl-alt-T` opens `st` now, part of the problem still remains. It could be a different problem, but I use vim and vim is the default for certain files. I did whatever you suggested but still when I click on files vim opens them in the old terminal. How do I make all applications use `st` terminal?

Comment: Another example, when I run `xdg-open \`fzf\`` the selected file opens in old terminal. Thats not desirable as well.

Comment: For `vim` you need probably need to edit the `vim` desktop entry `/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop` by creating a copy in `.local/share/applications/`. I think `xdg-open` use `x-terminal-emulator` that we can not modify since  `st` is not listed by `update-alternatives`.

Comment: A non-elegant but general solution would be to link the old terminal to the new one: `ln -s /usr/bin/st ~/.local/bin/old-terminal` (logout needed to take effect).

Comment: I don't at all know how to edit the `vim.desktop` entry, I looked into the file there didn't seem to an option to set a terminal. Maybe need to add new code, didn't find anything online about this. How do I edit it?

Comment: It seems like no matter what new terminal I use vim will use the old-terminal, unless I edit `vim.desktop`.

Comment: My old terminal is `gnome terminal`, it's located in `/usr/bin`. The symlink fails.

Comment: Check the new edit of my answer.

Comment: After editing `vim.desktop` `st` does close instantly. So I tried the brutal solution (after deleting `~/.loca/share/applications/vim.desktop`). Now after symlink-ing when I click on a file it isn't opening at all. Don't know what's going on.

Why does vim still use the old terminal though? What if I delete/uninstall the (default provided) `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Vim probably uses the terminal emulator defined my `xdg-open` that's why it is still using `gnome-terminal`. You should try to reselect Vim as default application to open those files in your file manager.

Comment: In that case, I was trying to change `xdg-open` settings, tried `xdg-settings` but didn't see the terminal option there. Is there a way to change that setting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109746/discussion-between-loic-reynier-and-mahbub-alam).

Answer (score 1):

If `st` is not present as an option if you run `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator` you can add it to the `update-alternatives` with the following command: `sudo update-alternatives --install <link> <name> <path> <priority>`.

In my case it looks like this: `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/st 100`.

After you executed the command you should be able to see and select `st` if you now run
`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change the XTERM variable from `/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator` to `st`

My `x-terminal-emulator` is pointing to lxterm